# How to write a script for extracting column names from an xl file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Here I am trying to get the "university" from the 3rd column and I wrote a script like this

```
import xlrd 

loc = ("names.xlsx") 

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc) 
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 
sheet.cell_value(0, 3) 

for i in range(sheet.nrows): 
    print(sheet.cell_value(i, 3))
```

With this script I am getting the overall 3rd column from my xl sheet now I need to get only the sentences having "university" can anyone please help me out
Example data:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the values from column 3 containing 'university' add the following to your for loop

```
for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    if 'university' in str(sheet.cell_value(i, 3)):
        print(sheet.cell_value(i, 3))
```

Comment: Yes I got it @Lambo thankyou can you guide me in another issue if you dont mind

Comment: Actually in the first column in this excel sheet I am having names so I want to get the names which are having university in their 3rd column in this same excel sheet

Comment: Can you please paste and example of your data

Comment: yes I had added a screenshot of my excel see @lambo

Comment: I`m unable to open the image